# Background Cronjobs are turning into Zombie processes

Tags: linux, cron, zombie-process, sles

I have 60 cronjobs scheduled to be run after reboot as background jobs as mentioned below:

```
@reboot sleep 900 && /home/creta/Scripts/N1/./N1_Docs.sh > /dev/null 2> /home/creta/Scripts/N1/N1_Docs.log &
```

All these background scripts are turning into zombie although they are working as expected.

Scripts as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
while true; do
    for z in "/D1/N1/*.pdf"; do
        /usr/bin/rclone move /D1/N1/ New:D1/N1/ --log-file=/home/user/Scripts/N1/N1_Docs.log
    done  
    sleep 18
done
```

Why are they turning into zombie and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the reason to put `cron` job in background? Your script is infinite loop, I do not see any logic for exit the loop. And you never use variable `z`, why you have `for` loop?

Comment: I want the script to check for PDF files in the directory and if PDF files are present, want to move those to Gdrive. Since I am using SLES 15, we do not have /etc/rc.local to specify the background jobs using nohup thats why I have I have used cronjobs. Yes these scripts needs to be running all the time

Comment: @RomeoNinov please look into it. This issue is in production.

Comment: Few points: how often there files appear in the directory. How much you can loose from them? What to do if file appear partially in the directory? What is the accepted interval between appear in first directory and be moved to second directory?

Comment: Files are uploaded to the Application Server as per the Clients requirement, randomly we can not predict and due to the same partial appearance of file wont be the case here. We can not loose any data. Since there are almost 78 such background scripts I have induced some of the scripts to sleep 0 and some as sleep 18 and some as sleep 30.

Comment: My main concern here cronjobs converting into Zombie and why? How can we fix this issue?

Comment: `cron` is not a good way for such job, better create service/daemon which run the script. About zombies - have you consider its from `rclone`? Also remove `for` loop you do not need it, it there are no PDFs there will be no sync.

Comment: So do I need to have 78 deamons to run each script

Comment: Why 78? You can combine several (or all) directories sync in one script.